# I need to find the formula for h(x) for all x

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, improper-integrals

we're given a function $h(x)=\begin{cases}1/2&\text{for}&0\le x<2\\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Then we are told to define the function $\displaystyle g(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} h(y)h(x-y)dy$ I need to find the formula for $h(x)$ for all $x$.

what i believe i need to do is a double integral with integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ as outside integral and integral from $0$ to $2$ of $\frac{1}{2}h(x-y)$

i don't know how to handle the $h(x-y)$ part

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $h(y) h(x-y) = 1/4$ if ... and $0$ otherwise.  Draw a picture of this region in the $xy$ plane.

Comment: i get the 1/4 because h(y)*h(x-y)=(1/2)*(1/2) so then i evaluate this on integral from 0 to 2 wrt y. leaving me wih an integral from -infinity to infinity of 1/2 dx

Comment: @Snufsan is that what u meant

Comment: First fill in the ....  Then draw the region.  Then integrate.

Comment: oh 0<y<x-y as my limits

Answer (score 0):

Note that the integral is over $y$ and $x$ is a constant, so obviously the domain for $h(y)$ is $[0,2]$, but $x-y$ might not be in $[0,2]$ and then it is equal to $0$, therefore, you need to find out for which $x$, you have $y$'s that $x-y$ is also in $[0,2]$ when $y$ is in that interval.

Comment: im still really confused

Comment: Try to use @RobertIsrael hint

Comment: how can you do h(x-y) when we're told that h(x)=1/2

Comment: the integration is with respect to $y$, then $x$ is no different then $34983765$